Logarithmic transformation of Poisson R.V. is asymptotically normal as $\lambda\to\infty$?
Let $K\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and
$$
V(K)=\log(K/\beta+1)
$$
for some $\beta>0$.
Claim: The distribution of $V$ is asymptotically normal as $\lambda\to\infty$.

Thoughts:
Lemma #1: $K\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal N(\lambda,\lambda)$ as $\lambda\to\infty$.  This can be proven by showing that the characteristic function of
$$
K^\prime=\frac{K-\lambda}{\sqrt \lambda}
$$
converges to the characteristic function of $\mathcal N(0,1)$ as $\lambda\to\infty$.
Lemma #2: Let $\tilde V(K)$ be the first-order expansion of $V(K)$ about $\mathsf EK=\lambda$:
$$
\tilde V(K)=\log(\lambda/\beta+1)+\frac{K-\lambda}{\lambda+\beta}.
$$
Since the logarithm is concave, $\tilde V(x)\geq V(x)$ with equality when $x=\lambda$. It can be shown that
$$
I(n,\lambda)=\int_{\lambda-n\sqrt\lambda}^{\lambda+n\sqrt\lambda} (\tilde V(x)-V(x))\,\mathrm dx
$$
for some $n>0$ is positive and $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}I(n,\lambda)=0$.
Assuming I have made no mistakes in Lemma #2, it would follow that as $\lambda\to\infty$ the function $V(x)$ and $\tilde V(x)$ converge pointwise on the interval $x\in[\lambda-n\sqrt\lambda,\lambda+n\sqrt\lambda]$. For large enough $n$, $\mathsf P(K\in[\lambda-n\sqrt\lambda,\lambda+n\sqrt\lambda])\approx 1$ and thus as $\lambda$ increases $V(K)$ converges in distribution to the linear transformation
$$
V(K)\overset{d}{\to}\tilde V(K).
$$
But since $K$ is asymptotically normal $V(K)$ is approaching a linear transformation of a normal variable and thus is normal.
Thoughts?

Edit:
As pointed out by @Henry, a normalization of $V(K)$ is needed.
Since $\mathsf E\tilde V=\log(\lambda/\beta+1)$ and $\mathsf{Var}\tilde V=\lambda/(\lambda+\beta)^2$ we define the normalization
$$
V_n=\frac{V-\mathsf E\tilde V}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}\tilde V}}=\frac{\lambda+\beta}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\log\left(\frac{K/\beta+1}{\lambda/\beta+1}\right).
$$
Matlab simulation using $\lambda=10000$ and $\beta=1$ yields results consistent with $V_n\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$:


Presumably your $H=\lambda$.  The delta method might be more natural to get the result.

@Henry yes, my bad. I corrected the post by replacing H with $\lambda$.

@Henry I would agree the delta method has some tie to my question but there is a difference.  As $\lambda$ increases, the logarithmic function and linear approximation converge pointwise over a region where the support of the Poisson distribution is nearly one. So it seems that $V$ may actually be asymptotically normal as $\lambda\to\infty$.

The variance of your $V$ will head towards $0$ and its expectation towards $\infty$ as $\lambda$ increases, so you are going to need a relocation and rescaling to get anything meaningful

@Henry are you able to prove that $\mathsf{Var}V\to 0$ as $\lambda\to\infty$?

I looked at it empirically, which suggested $\lambda ,\textrm{Var}V\to 1$ and $E[V]-\log(\lambda) \to -\log(\beta)$ as $\lambda \to \infty$
